# Ito's Lemma and Ito's Integral

Tags: integration

I have a Brownian Motion *Wt* defined in the probability space (Ω,F,P).
By using the Ito's lemma or Ito's integral I have to prove that:

$$\int_0^T u\operatorname dW_u ~=~ W_T~T ~–~ \int_0^T W_u\operatorname du$$

the Integration is from 0 to T.

I don't understand how to approach this problem when I have to apply the Ito's lemma to an integral because I am used to do the opposite. Thus, I don't understand if I have to integrate and then start to compute the partial derivatives. I have tried like this, but I don't get the equation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Tip: This is just Integration by Parts.
$$\int u\operatorname d v ~=~ u~v -\int v\operatorname d u$$

Comment: But if I try to use the integration by parts I don't have the same results. Also because it is asked to use the Ito's Lemma or Integral.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{T}u\,dW_u=\int_{0}^{T}\int_{0}^{u}\,dt\,dW_u=\int_{0}^{T}\int_{t}^{T}\,dW_u\,dt=\int_{0}^{T}(W_T-{W_t})dt$$
then
$$\int_{0}^{T}u\,dW_u=T\,W_T-\int_{0}^{T}W_t\,dt$$